# maximum stack size exceeded when forcefully making a div empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using nicEdit editor where if I add something to contenteditable div and give some style to it, and then remove everything from div and again type something, it takes previous styles in a span tag with that inline style. I tried to make that div empty forcefully using below code

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
        $j('.nicEdit-main').bind('DOMNodeRemoved', function (event) {
            if (this.innerHTML == "" || this.innerHTML == "<br>")
                this.innerHTML = "";
        });
    }
});
```

But now I am getting "maximum stack size exceeded" error in console.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that setting `innerHTML` triggers a `DOMNodeRemoved` event, so **you enter into a loop of events, which at some point will go over the stack size**. Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/38b7zd9b/1/

Anyway, It's a little bit unclear what you are trying to accomplish with the code above and why are you using the mutation event, but be aware that you are using an unsupported/deprecated API, and that means that API is not reliable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events